# Как проверить наличие русского или английского текста?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby

Нужно добавить фильтр, чтобы отображать записи либо с русскими, либо с английскими заголовками.

Сейчас на ум приходит только проверка регулярным выражением:

```
([а-яА-ЯеЁ])
([a-zA-Z])
```

Нормальное ли это решение? Или есть какой-нибудь лучший (для Ruby) вариант? Или же даже можно как-то в SQL (PostgreSQL) запросе сделать проверку?

Comment: Как общаетесь с постгресом? Через AR? Тогда есть смысл добавить метку `ruby-on-rails`.

Comment: @D-side да, верно, через ar. Добавил метку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Очень даже можно прямо в PostgreSQL

Вот пример скоупа для ActiveRecord:

```
scope :title_matching_regex, -> (r) { where('title ~ :regex', regex: r) }
```

Решение на уровне Ruby может быть разве что пост-процессингом результатов из PostgreSQL, но поскольку оно будет делать примерно то же самое, проще отобрать нужные данные сразу до получения их из БД.

*У PostgreSQL с кириллицей получше, чем у Ruby, но я всё равно не уверен, что с кириллицей оно отработает так же гладко. Проверьте.*

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо. Проверю.